# Django decorator, adding method to WSGIRequest

Tags: django, metaprogramming, request, wsgi

Using a decorator I was trying to add a method to WSGIRequest request, just like is_ajax().
Since I could not find a proper way I just updated request.META with the info needed.

Should I look into adding method at runtime in Python ?

Comment: Can you tell us why a new method is required? What does this method do?

Comment: indeed just request.foo = mymethod is needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write custom middleware and add this method to request during request process.

See this for more info how to write middleware:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter16/